# django and angularJS permission_required anonymousUser

Tags: django, angularjs

i'm writing a django / angularjs application, and i'm trying to use the @permission_required for user permission authorization.

I'm returning from the client side both headers- sessionId and csrf token, and yet the @permission_required method user, is anonymousUser, although when i'm logging in the user, i use - login(request, user) method, and the user arg is updated to the current user:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def log_in_view(request):
    body = request.body
    json_body = json.loads(body)
    email = json_body.get("email")
    password = json_body.get('password')
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    session = request.session

    if user is not None:
        request.session['email'] = email
        request.session['password'] = password
        session.set_expiry(900)
        session.save()
        session_key = session.session_key
        login(request, user)
        crcf = get_token(request)
        response_body = {}
        response_body.update({"session_key" : session_key})
        response_body.update({"csrf" : crcf})
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_body), content_type="text/json", status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("could not authenticate user", content_type="text/plain", status=401)
```

does anyone have any idea what am i doing wrong?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

you dont need all those stuff to login the user. I mean you dont need to set up session manually, either return csrf token.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def log_in_view(request):
    body = request.body
    json_body = json.loads(body)
    email = json_body.get("email")
    password = json_body.get('password')
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

    if user:
        login(request, user)
        response_body = {}
        response_body['user'] = user
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_body), content_type="text/json", status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("could not authenticate user", content_type="text/plain", status=401)
```

Answer (score 0):

By use of @api_view I'm assuming that you're using Django REST Framework.

Each api view of django rest framework don't rely by default on django authentication. If you want your view to use django authentication, you should add proper `@authentication_classes(...)` decorator to your view or specify it globally in your settings.py file.